# HQL запрос с подзапросом

Tags: hql

Подскажите пожалуйста как в HQL написать запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM document 
    where mydate BETWEEN '2008-08-02' AND '2008-08-07'
    ) t
    where mydate BETWEEN '2008-07-01' AND '2008-08-10';
```

Пишу в HQL в таком виде (ниже) ругается на скобку в первой строке после from

```
    SELECT t FROM (
    SELECT d  
    FROM Document d 
    where mydate BETWEEN '2008-08-02' AND '2008-08-07'
    ) t
    where mydate BETWEEN '2008-07-01' AND '2008-08-10';
```